# Accessing source files from git BARE:master

Tags: git

I'm certain that I'm missing something fundamental here, but I've received a drop of an application stored in a git repository. It has folders like: branches, hooks, objects, etc, but no actual source files.

When I open up git bash and cd into that folder, the title says "(BARE:master)".

I assume I just need to somehow clone a local reposisitory from that folder. Ultimately, I just need access to the actual source files in the repository, but I'm surely missing some concept as I'm somewhat new to git.

Any hints or help on how I can get this set up locally would be appreciated.

*edit: when I try to clone from that directory I receive the following error*

```
$ git clone c:/Users/Joel/Dropbox/TheProjectDirectory.git
Cloning into LocalProjectFolder ...
fatal: 'c:/Users/Joel/Dropbox/TheProjectDirectory.git' does not appear to be a git
 repository

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Could you give us more info? Is it your local repository without any remotes? Or you've cloned it from some url like your company's server or github or anything else? It's hard to give you useful advice without re-telling half of the book on Git when we don't know what you're trying to do with git...

Comment: understood, you'll have to forgive me as I'm new to git it's hard to know what is important info. The directory was given to me as a shared DropBox folder. I've not cloned anything myself, just accepted the shared dropbox folder, and am now trying to access the source files

Comment: Then it is perfectly ok to have shared folder bare. I'll try to explain what is happening here in a moment as edit to my answer...

Comment: Here you go. If you still have any questions - you're welcome :)

Comment: Just noticed that you're using paths `c:/something`. You should try `/c/something` instead. At least I'm using msysgit and its bash shell on my Win box and it is working only with `/c/something` paths.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is bare repository what you have.

The simplest way to get sources is to clone it via `git clone /path/to/your/bare/rep`

The bare repositories is something like shared repository, where work from several developers get gathered. For developer box you most probably want non-bare one.

There's a [chapter](http://progit.org/book/ch2-1.html) about cloning repositories.

EDIT:
So, I have some git repository on my box. So I'll try to emulate your situation. First I'll clone my repository as bare one:

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test
$ git clone --bare /d/work/gittesting/ bare.git
Cloning into bare repository bare.git...
done.

idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test
$ cd bare.git/

idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/bare.git (BARE:master)
```

So here I have bare.git repository like you have your shared folder. Now I will clone it to have some working directory with actual sources:

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/bare.git (BARE:master)
$ cd ..

idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test
$ git clone bare.git/ my-non-bare-dev-rep
Cloning into my-non-bare-dev-rep...
done.

idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test
$ cd my-non-bare-dev-rep/

idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/my-non-bare-dev-rep (master)
```

Now I have folder `my-non-bare-dev-rep` and all files from repository are there. It is you working copy. String `(master)` is the hint for you that you are in the `master` branch now.

Then I'll emulate some work in my working copy.

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/my-non-bare-dev-rep (master)
$ echo 'my new text' > text-file.txt
```

I want to see changes I have in working copy comparing with the version I got from shared rep:

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/my-non-bare-dev-rep (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       text-file.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Now I will add this text file to so-called *stage area* (or sometimes it is called *index*). It is the term to describe a set of changes that will be committed when `git commit` command is executed.

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/my-non-bare-dev-rep (master)
$ git add text-file.txt
```

Well now text-file.txt is in the stage area. But it is still not committed. It is time to do this:

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/my-non-bare-dev-rep (master)
$ git commit -m 'my commit from dev repo'
[master c0b0bd8] my commit from dev repo
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 text-file.txt
```

So. Now it is stored in my local repository. In the `.git` folder actually. But it is still not went to shared repo so that my colleagues also see it. For this I need to do a `push`:

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/my-non-bare-dev-rep (master)
$ git push origin
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 290 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To d:/test/bare.git/
   d01886b..c0b0bd8  master -> master
```

`origin` is a standard name git gives to parent when you did a clone. So as I did clone from bare.git - my changes just went there.
And finally to get updates from shared folder into your local repository you have to execute `pull` command:

```
idanilov@IDANILOV-PC /d/test/my-non-bare-dev-rep (master)
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

I don't have any changes pushed to bare.git from other places, so my local rep is up-to-date. And git told me so.

Comment: when I try that, I get the error I noted above (edited the question)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
git clone /c/some/dir.git
```

In git bash. C: type paths are not handled well.